# How to edit the GUI of a QGIS plugin not made with the plugin builder?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, compile

I edited a python plugin's code and had to change the UI a bit as well. However, unlike in the plugins I made from scratch with the plugin builder, the UI doesn't automatically update in QGIS when I change the .ui file with Qt designer and reload the plugin. I figured I'd have to compile it (to .py) manually with

```
"C:\Program Files\QGIS Chugiak\bin\pyrcc4" -o ui_changeDSDialog.py ui_changeDSDialog.ui
```

but that just throws a "No resources in resource description." error. How do I compile it?

**/edit:** pyuic4 doesn't work either.

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

Nor does `-x -o`

Comment: You don't need to compile it. There should be a change after you reload plugins. If there are changes in xml file and its not working, there must be something wrong with your QGIS.

Comment: Hmm okay, I don't need to compile it (to .pyc). However, the .py file does not change when I change the .ui file. I can open the .py file in a text editor and edit the ui elements textually, which is reflected in QGIS. So the question still remains.. how do I go from .ui to .py? Maybe compiling is the wrong word. Translating?

Comment: It shouldn't change. Your ui_changeDSDialog.py contains only one class, which is constructor and it doesn't change after editing ui.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, in the first comment you said it should change (on its own?), now it shouldn't?

Comment: In first comment I wrote about ui_changeDSDialog.ui, It's pure xml file.

Comment: QGIS reads the .py, not the .ui. I know that all I have to do is change the .ui file for plugins created with the plugin builder, but as I said this one wasn't built with it and nothing happens when I just change the .ui file.